# Idle doesn't hold on 2006 Toyota pick up truck after giving a jump, actually failing to give a jump.

Tags: electrical, battery, rough-idle, jump-start

We have a 2006 toyota pick up truck and a 2000 mustang with a dead battery.  Cable's have been Properly connected.  1, I can get no current flow, no jump from the toyota, yet it starts the pick up just fine. 2, the pick up truck now will not hold it's idle.  It idle's down until it's ready to die out.  Can trying to get a jump from the pick up truck cause the throttle to lose it's idle setting?  No blown fuses, relays, no electrical system problems.  Just the throttle lost it's idle setting.
A mechanic who reset the throttle, and flushed it (milked it really), says a power surge could have happened.  Power surge? From where, the dead battery?  I know nobody likes to say I don't know, but I'm pretty sure he didn't know what caused the problem.  I'm going with a freakish coincidence.   Any ideas?, theory's?                          Thank you for your thoughts and help.  John

Comment: is it an electric throttle?

Comment: @Ben from pictures on the Google, it looks like the Tacoma and Tundra both have electronic throttles.

Comment: Will the truck rev normally? Either way, it's probably worth disconnecting the battery for a few minutes under the "have you tried turning it off and on again?" doctrine. This will initiate the idle re-learn and TPS reset procedures (at least it does on my Nissan). Be warned: disconnecting the battery will delete your radio presets, and may lock out the radio as well, so be sure you have the factory reset code if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

If the mechanic did something to your throttle body and it dies now not a long after start, it is obvious to me that it only needs an idle adjustment. I would say needs to clean it first, but if the mechanic done it already, just adjust it. I believe your truck has a throttle cable, and the throttle body looks like this:[image]

The ugly yellow arrow points at screw that you need to screw in a bit, you will need a 7 or 8 mm spanner (I'm guessing, might be 10mm) and 3 or 4 mm allen key. Undo the nut, screw it in about 1/2 turn, start the car, if it dies, turn it another 1/2 turn. Let it warm up (3 minutes), and then screw slowly out. When it sounds lovely and not shaking or roaring :D tighten the nut and enjoy your first mechanical job ;)

Comment: Great answer, but the Tacoma and Tundra have electronic throttles, so it does not apply to this situation.